# automatically set jQuery UI datepicker on load

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When a form load I want it to already have the current date *plus* 5 days. So its 2/22/2011, When the page loads the text box the datepicker belongs to should show 3/1/2011. I know how to set default date to 5 days from the current date but I need it to be in the text box when the page loads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a much easier way.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "+5d");
```

Just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something, you would do something like:

```
$(function() {
    //set your date picker
    $('#test').datepicker();

    //get the current date
    var yourDate = new Date();
    //set the current date to today + 5 days
    yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() + 5)
    //format the date in the right format
    formatDate = (yourDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + yourDate.getDate() + '/' + yourDate.getFullYear();
    //set the input value
    $('#test').val(formatDate);
});
```

[Working sample here here...](http://jsfiddle.net/WpUu3/)